# r language question: Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

Tags: r, random-forest

i'm using
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/ prcocessed.cleveland.data
to do random forest

```
sample = sample.split(processed_cleveland$num, SplitRatio = .75)

train = subset(processed_cleveland, sample == TRUE)

test  = subset(processed_cleveland, sample == FALSE)

rf <- randomForest(
         num ~ .,
         processedcleveland=train
    )
```

And then it shows

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
'.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

I don't know how to resolve it

Comment: it should be `randomForest(num ~ . , data=train)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `randomForest` function expects an argument called `data`, but you're trying to pass your data, `train`, to an argument called `processedcleveland`.

This should fix it:

```
rf <- randomForest(
         num ~ .,
         data=train
    )
```